# Swapping contents of a line in a list, if keyword present

Tags: python

How can I change the contents of a line in a list, if that line contains a certain string?

If my file contains "Please delete this" I want to change that to a blank line.

For example:

```
for line in Thelist:
    if "Please Delete This" in line:
        line in Thelist = "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access list elements with index. 
The simplest way to achieve it is using `enumerate` to
get line index alongside the `line`

```
for i, line in enumerate(Thelist):
    if "Please Delete This" in line:
        Thelist[i] = "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Thelist` is a list of strings, you can use an index to iterate over it and change its content via index when needed.

```
for index in range(len(Thelist)):
    if "Please Delete This" in Thelist[index]:
        Thelist[index] = '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension for accomplishing the task:

```
Thelist = ['This is line 1',
           'This is line 2',
           'Please Delete This',
           'This is another line']

Thelist = ['\n' if "Please Delete This" in line else line for line in Thelist]

print(Thelist)
```

Output:

```
['This is line 1', 'This is line 2', '\n', 'This is another line']
```

Comment: Empty string  instead of newline seems to be sufficient and allows more uniform further processing.